# Unable to provision Application Insight resource using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am facing an issue while trying to provision an Application Insight resource in our subscription using Terraform. 
Terraform spits the following error

> azurerm_application_insights.global_app_function_insight: Error
>   creating Application Insights "hub-deployer-insight-globalsg"
>   (Resource Group "hub-globalsg-rg"):
>   insights.ComponentsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request:
>   StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an
>   error. Status= Code="MissingRegistrationForLocation" Message="The
>   subscription is not registered for the resource type 'components' in
>   the location 'northcentralus'. Please re-register for this provider in
>   order to have access to this location."

I have tried unregistering then re-registering the provider in the subscription in question, but the issue remains. Have anyone experienced similar issue so far?

I've research the issue a bit, but none were related to Terraform. Some were releted to the .NET SDK version people were using, so maybe an issue with the Azure SDK for Go... or maybe an issue with our subscription...

`terraform_version: 0.11.8`

`provider-azurerm_version: 1.19.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not terraform related. I've seen this happen sometimes. Try deploying application insights to the northcentralus region from the portal and then try using terraform.

Comment: This is exactly what we ended up doing since we needed that resource anyway and we didn't encounter any issue provisioning it using the portal...